# Steps to send a file with FTP?

Tags: macos, terminal, ftp

I can connect to my server in my terminal with `ftp`command. Then, I connect to my site with `open xxx` but I don't know how to send file from my computer (local) to this server, with `put`.

Can someone explain it to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `put` and add a space after that command, you can then drag a file into the terminal window, it will paste the full path to the filename and add the extension from the filesystem.

Press enter and the transfer from the Mac to the server should start...

Answer (score 1):

FTP is one of the oldest file transfer commands, quite as old as the `telnet` command. Here is a short usage, although I encourage you to use scp or sftp instead of, because basic ftp transmits username and password in cleartext through the wire, except using the ftp-s protocol, which opens a SSL based connection (that requires a client capable of doing this).

To open a ftp connection to a destination server from the terminal:

`$ ftp <server>`

After logging in with username and password, list directory with `ls` and `cd`into the required directory.

Depending on the server configuration, you can get or put files:

`get <filename>`

`put <filename>`

If it is a binary file like an archive, switch on binary transfer mode first by issueing the `bin` command first.

Close the connection by sending `quit`.

There is always the `help` command to see all allowed and available commands:

`ftp> help`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with SFTP, will check that :)
Else, @bmike answer resolved the problem.